# Bash with JQ grouping

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a file with a stream of JSON objects as follows:

```
{"id":4496,"status":"Analyze","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"state":"New","code":"RNPD.DEREF","title":"Suspicious dereference of pointer before NULL check","message":"Suspicious dereference of pointer \u0027peer-\u003esctSapCb\u0027 before NULL check at line 516","file":"/home/build/branches/mmm/file1","method":"CzUiCztGpReq","owner":"unowned","taxonomyName":"C and C++","dateOriginated":1473991086512,"url":"http://xxx/yyy","issueIds":[4494]}
{"id":4497,"status":"Analyze","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"state":"New","code":"NPD.GEN.CALL.MIGHT","title":"Null pointer may be passed to function that may dereference it","message":"Null pointer \u0027tmpEncodedPdu\u0027 that comes from line 346 may be passed to function and can be dereferenced there by passing argument 1 to function \u0027SCpyMsgMsgF\u0027 at line 537.","file":"/home/build/branches/mmm/file1","method":"CzUiCztGpReq","owner":"unowned","taxonomyName":"C and C++","dateOriginated":1473991086512,"url":"http://xxx/yyy/zzz","issueIds":[4495]}
{"id":4498,"status":"Analyze","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"state":"New","code":"NPD.GEN.CALL.MIGHT","title":"Null pointer may be passed to function that may dereference it","message":"Null pointer \u0027tmpEncodedPdu\u0027 that comes from line 346 may be passed to function and can be dereferenced there by passing argument 1 to function \u0027SCpyMsgMsgF\u0027 at line 537.","file":"/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c","method":"CzUiCztGpReq","owner":"unowned","taxonomyName":"C and C++","dateOriginated":1473991086512,"url":"http://xxx/yyy/zzz","issueIds":[4495]}
```

I would like to get with JQ (or in some other way), three lines, one each for the ids, the URLs, and the file name:

This is what I have so far:

```
cat /tmp/file.json | ~/bin_compciv/jq --raw-output '.id,.url,.file'
```

Result:

```
4496
http://xxx/yyy
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
.
.
.
```

**BUT** - I would like to group them by file name, so that I will get comma-separated lists of urls and ids on the same line, like this:

```
4496,4497
http://xxx/yyy,http://xxx/yyy/zzz
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
```

Comment: Better to run `jq ... </tmp/file.json` or (also completely POSIX-legal!) `</tmp/file.json jq ...` rather than `cat /tmp/file.json | jq ...` -- the former starts up `cat` as a separate process, and give `jq` a read-once pipeline to get content from that pipeline, whereas the latter gives `jq` a real, seekable, introspectable handle on the actual input file.

Comment: That doesn't matter so much for `jq` here, but it can matter a lot for, say, `sort` -- if it has a real file handle, an optimized implementation of `sort` can have subprocesses seek to different parts of the file, sort components in parallel, and then do a merge sort at the parent process; with a non-seekable FIFO for input you can't do that kind of optimization without a non-parallelizable initial read pass, as the input stream can be read only once, front-to-back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one minor exception, you can readily achieve the stated goals using jq as follows:

```
jq -scr 'map({id,url,file})
  | group_by(.file)
  | .[]
  | ((map(.id) | @csv) , (map(.url) | @csv), (.[0] | .file))'
```

Given your input, the output would be:

```
4496,4497
"http://xxx/yyy","http://xxx/yyy/zzz"
/home/build/branches/mmm/file1
4498
"http://xxx/yyy/zzz"
/home/build/branches/mmm/otherfile.c
```

You could then eliminate the quotation marks using a text-editing tool such as `sed`; using another invocation of `jq`; or as described below.  However, this might not be such a great idea if there's ever any chance that any of the URLs contains a comma.

Here's the filter for eliminating the quotation marks with just one invocation of jq:

```
map({id,url,file})
| group_by(.file)
| .[]
| ((map(.id) | @csv),
   ([map(.url) | join(",")] | @csv | .[1:-1]),
   (.[0] | .file))
```

Comment: Looks like it's what I'm looking for. But ran it like this:
cat /tmp/file.json | ~/bin_compciv/jq -scr 'map({id,url,file}) | group_by(.file)| .[] | ((map(.id) | @csv) , (map(.url) | @csv))'
It says -scr not recognized. Tried without -scr, got error: "jq: error: Cannot index array with string
jq: error: array is not valid in a csv row"

Comment: Evidently you are not using the latest version of jq (1.5).  If you are using v. 1.4, use "-s -c -r" instead of -scr.  If you are using 1.3 then other changes may be needed, but it would be preferable to upgrade to at least v1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **group_by** and the `-r`, `-s` jq options:

```
  group_by(.file)[]

| ([ "\(.[].id)" ] | join(",")),
  ([ .[].url     ] | join(",")),
     .[0].file
```